# My post request value with special character getting encoded

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, c#-3.0

I have a multi form where I have few field like name ,file name and one pdf file and  I am hitting one api with post method to store the values and pdf in a data base but when I send the req if my filename consists any special character it gets encoded in url encoded value and then getting stored in database .
The tech stack i am using is dot net .so please help me out anyone.